# Код не исполняется после app.exec_()

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, closeevent, qapplication

Как сделать так, чтобы код после `app.exec_()` был выполнен?

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)


app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()

text = QLabel(window)

window.show()
app.exec_()

text.setText("Hello, world")      # этот код не будет выполнен :(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как вы задумали - не получится. Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.label = QLabel("Label", self)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.label.setText("Hello, world")
        QApplication.processEvents()        
        QThread.msleep(3000)   
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except SystemExit:
        print('Closing Window... ')
```